# what is the best way to create a matrix of array lists (array lists of objects) and how should I initialize it?

Tags: java, matrix, arraylist

I want to create a matrix that contains 5 arrary list.
each array list contains different objects but from the same types (they all Actors but every array list contains a different actor...)
how should I initialize it?
it's basically a game. I want to initialize every actor in the array lists with a position and the general matrix with all the actors/array lists.

Comment: Have you tried this: `ArrayList<ArrayList<Actor>>` ?

Comment: yes but I need a matrix to represent the board of the game. so if i'm using an array list of array lists how do i initialize it? and how do i get to each actor later..

Comment: Can you explain your last line: **the general matrix with all the actors/array lists.**? Also, do you want a matrix, that is, a 2d array containing arraylists? `matrix[][]` something like this? Check out my answer.

Answer (score 0):

> create a matrix that contains 5 array lists

```
ArrayList[] matrix = new ArrayList[5];
```

> each array list contains different objects but from the same types

```
matrix[0] = new ArrayList<MyCustomClass>();
matrix[0].add(new MyCustomClass(...));
matrix[0].add(new MyCustomClass(...));
```

> how do i get to each actor later

```
// one way of getting the Actor object if you know 
matrix[0].get(index);the index
```

If you don't know the index, then you will have to traverse the arraylist and find the Actor you want.